# How to make a function wait for 60 seconds after each iteration?

Tags: python, loops, datetime, time, timedelta

Hii Stack members i'm trying to run a function just for one iteration or second and then it should wait for 60seconds/01minute to again run the function.

It should then do it infinitely until the run time.

The function is like this

```
def ROC(self,df,tick):
    global start_time 
    global timespan
    start_time = tick['exchange_timestamp']
    prev_volume = tick['volume_traded']
```

As this code will be used inside a class as a method so multithreading/multiprocessing won't work and moreover if i'll use `time.sleep(60)` of time package of python then the whole code will wait for this segment to over so this way it'll also not work.

The only way to solve this is by looping over time or datetime package of python or by using some scheduling method so if anyone could help me then it'd be great. :)

Thanks.

Comment: you can use [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) to schedule a job

Comment: You could improve your question with the code that shows the context. As it seems you want to run something else in parallel which is not shown as an example in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need multithreading if you want anything to be executed while something else waits. I can't think of a reason why your function being a method of a class will prevent that though.

You can use `threading.Timer` to put `ROC` on a 60-second timer:

```
t = threading.Timer(60.0, ROC)
t.start()
```

This will create a thread that will execute the function 60 seconds after you call start(). The time it will take is whatever processing time is required for what you put inside the function.

To then continually re-run the function after 60s, you can then start the next thread on the old one:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import threading
import time

def hello():
    t = threading.Timer(60.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print("hello world")

hello()
```

Starting the new timer at the beginning rather than the end decreases the amount of drift that will happen due to the execution time of the function itself.

If you really need the function to run for exactly 1 second, you can `time.sleep(1)` inside it, but this will result in the function running for the processing time + 1s, so you still have some drift. You can measure the time at the beginning and end of `ROC()` and sleep for the difference to get closer to execution time of exactly 1s:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import threading
import time

def hello():
    start_at = datetime.now()
    t = threading.Timer(60.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print("hello world")
    end_at = datetime.now()

    execution_time = timedelta(seconds=1)-(end_at-start_at)
    time.sleep(execution_time.total_seconds())

hello()
```

Comment: Hey @mijiturka i tried with your above soln but it didn't helped me out. I also tried with time.sleep(60) but it's running the thread every second instead of waiting for 60 seconds.

Comment: Can you give some suggestion of how to use time or datetime package of python in this issue like making **start_time** and **end_time** and then looping over this variables to solve this.

Comment: I lead you astray with the info on what threading.Timer does; I've editted the answer to include tested examples now.